# Tomato Sauce Turns Dark/Sweet

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

I tried to make my own tomato sauce from fresh tomatoes using a slow-cooker (for quite a long time). I gather this may not have been a good idea because the result is very dark red and it's super sweet.  What happened?  Why did it change color and get so sweet?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24153/whats-the-source-of-the-sweetness-in-tomato-sauce-thats-simmered-for-at-least?rq=1

Comment: I suspect I caramelized it.  (It's really quite dark.)

Comment: Caramelization doesn't happen except in foods above boiling temperatures (and often much hotter).  What you're seeing is mostly the results of Maillard reactions in various components (along with perhaps some enzymatic browning early on).