# What is a good cut of meat to use in beef bourguignon

Tags: beef, slow-cooking

I'm looking for a nice cut of meat that would nicely fall apart when you put a fork to it. It doesn't have to follow the "authentic" recipe. I've tried various packs of "stew meat" before and it always comes out pretty rough. I'm willing to acknowledge I'm not cooking it properly or long enough. But I'm also wondering if maybe a brisket or a specific cut of meat would work better.

Comment: It does, thank you. Though it isn't clear to me what is considered a "long" vs short cook time.

Comment: A long cook is going to be between 2 & 4 hours. If you really want the fibres to break down, nearer 4. see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/96655/42066